# Index Redirect With Filter Options Saved In Session

Tags: php, laravel, filtering, state, laravel-blade

So what i have at the moment is a normal resource route with index, create, store, edit, update, the usual. In the Index I have a few filter options which filter out the entries. Simple enough. What I want to have is that the filter options be saved , and when you create, update or delete that when you are redirected back to the index that your filter options still be saved and filtered. The issue I'm having is that I don't want to be redirecting unnecessarily. The filter is in a form and it keeps posting to the index every time its values changes. In that case I don't want it to be a redirect. So far I've tried sorting out if its a redirect or just a filter that has changed. I want to be able to tell if the previous route is the same as the the current route in this case the index route. However the resource all start with the same route name. The redirect url is stored in the session under the 'cultivar_form_return_url' variable and then put into a variable to be used in checking if a redirect is required.

```
session(['cultivar_form_return_url' => $request->fullUrl()], '');
$redirect_url = $request->session()->get('cultivar_form_return_url', '');

if($redirect_url && !$has_filtered && !$filter) {
   return redirect($redirect_url);
}
$cultivars = $query
            ->orderBy('name')
            ->paginate(20);

return view('database.cultivars.index',compact('cultivars','filter','redirect_url'));
```

The $redirect_url is the url created when the filter request was submitted. I use this url to redirect to when I'm returning from a create, update or delete.
Which contains the parameters for the search. I check if the redirect_url exist, for the second parameter of the redirect i have created a variable that starts of as false, and if my request has parameters for the filter within each function i set the variable to true as follows.

```
if($request->has('input')) {
   $has_filtered = true;
   $query = $query->where('input', $request->input);
   $filter['input'] = $request->input;
}
```

The last parameter for the redirect check is the filter variable which contains my filter options which starts out as empty and gets set at each function if that particular filter is set.

```
$has_filtered = false;

    $query = (new Cultivar);

    $filter = [
        'search' => null,
        'crop' => null,
        'is_rootstock' => null,
        'is_public' => null,
    ];
```

I would like to differentiate between redirects and the filter options merely being changed. Thank You. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my previous answer, after a bit of testing still has a few bugs. So I have come up with a better solution. Instead of saving the redirect url to the session I put it into the form.php as one of the inputs. Both the edit and create works through the form.php. I just hid the field and use that field to keep track of the previous state which the filter was.

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="{{ $redirect_url }}">
```

The redirect route starts off as the generic route('database.cultivars.index') then I check if their is an old state in order to pass on the redirected route if there was a validation error or anything that might redirect you to the same page in order to keep the filter settings. Then I then I check if the previous route matches the current route and if it does that means the page was refreshed or there was a validation error. If The previous and current routes are not the same that means you just came from the index either for editing or creating. Then I grab that route and send it to the view to be put into the hidden field and the process gets repeated.

```
$redirect_url = route('database.cultivars.index');

if($request->old('redirect_url')) {
   $redirect_url = $request->old('redirect_url');
} else if(url()->previous() != route('database.cultivars.edit', $cultivar)) {
   $redirect_url = url()->previous();
}
```

When you have successfully created or updated a cultivar you are then redirected to the redirect Url if there is one. If there isn't one you are just redirected to route('database.cultivars.index'). This part is both in the store and update controller functions.

```
if($request->has('redirect_url')) {
    $redirect_url = $request->redirect_url;
}
    
if($redirect_url && starts_with($redirect_url, route('database.cultivars.index'))) {
    return redirect($redirect_url);
}
```

With this answer there are no bugs and no unnecessary redirects.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking more about the problem I think I might have an answer to my question.

```
$redirect_url = $request->session()->get('cultivar_form_return_url', '');

    if($redirect_url && !$has_filtered && url()->previous() != route('database.cultivars.index')) {

        session(['cultivar_form_return_url' => '']);

        return redirect($redirect_url);
    }

    session(['cultivar_form_return_url' => $request->fullUrl()]);
```

This stops it from redirecting to itself over and over while still keeping the filter options in. While also not redirecting unnecessarily.